# Have app give back free memory to linux?

Tags: c++, linux

Running this code in my VM (2gb) I use up about 40% of ram at point A and B. At point C regardless if I use shrink_to_fit or myresize memory jumps up to 79% of ram. At point C I'd like to give the OS back some memory. I'm mostly concerned that at 79% (instead of 40 where it could be) I may run apps and have linux terminate this app for using too much memory.

How do I give back free memory to the linux OS?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <deque>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

void myresize(deque<u64>&a) {
    a.shrink_to_fit(); return;
    deque<u64> b;
    for(auto i = a.begin(); i!=a.end(); ++i){
        b.push_back(*i);
    }
    a.swap(b);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    deque<u64> a;
    for(int i=0; i<100000000; ++i)
        a.push_back(i);

    printf("A\n");
    sleep(2);
    for(int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
        a.erase(a.begin()+i*3);
    printf("B\n");
    sleep(2);
    myresize(a);
    printf("C\n");
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe start from the man page for `mallopt` and follow the links?

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` already does what you want. There is no point in swapping afterwards. You are creating two `deque`s which occupy the same memory that's why you use twice as much memory

Comment: sorry i didnt understand the gcc implementation of what exactly?

Comment: @AaryamanSagar of shrink_to_fit. If you comment out that line so my code runs it will use the same amount of memory. I was shocked when memory doubled when I called shrink_to_fit()